# applying multiple limits

Tags: mysql

I have a table that goes as follows:

```
content_id | contact_count
         1              23
         2               4
         3              89
```

I want to select the content_id with the highest contact_count from the last 25 rows of the table.

I've tried many different things such as:

```
select content_id from research_products_content
   where contact_count=(select max(contact_count)
        from research_products_content order by rating_total_id desc limit 25)
   order by rating_total_id desc limit 1
```

Comment: How do you define the last 25 rows? The highest `contact_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `limit 25` is applied **after** the result (max, which is a single row) is selected. Try this instead:

```
SELECT tmp.content_id FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM research_products_content
  ORDER BY rating_total_id DESC
  LIMIT 25
  ) AS tmp
WHERE tmp.contact_count = (
  SELECT max(tmp2.contact_count)
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM research_products_content
    ORDER BY rating_total_id DESC
    LIMIT 25
  ) AS tmp2
)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Wow, I cannot thank you enough!  I've been struggling with this one query for a while now!  Out of curiosity, as I'm not too familiar with Mysql (but I'm starting to do a ton of php dev) would you be able to recommend some good SQL resources?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Consider marking the answer as accepted then :) In regards to SQL resources, I've never read any books, and didn't use any particular site (except for [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index.html), of course). Just googled around and read different articles. Sometimes even Wikipedia is a good place to start :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the column number will be the same use UNION

```
select content_id from research_products_content
   where contact_count=(select max(contact_count)
        from research_products_content order by rating_total_id desc limit 25)
UNION
select content_id from research_products_content
   where contact_count=(select max(contact_count)
        from research_products_content order by rating_total_id desc limit 1
```

You might want to implement caching along the way

Comment: Thanks Starx! I'm planning to implement memcached on my PHP server within the next few days!